# Pegar value do option e guardar em uma variavel para registrar no banco

Tags: php, mysql

```php
<p>Escolha a categoria:
        <select name="categoria">
        <option></option>
        <option value="v1">Conhecimentos gerais</option>
        <option value="v2">Português</option>
        <option value="v3">Matemática</option>
        <option value="v4">História</option>
        <option value="v5">Geografia</option>
        <option value="v6">Sociologia</option>
        <option value="v7">Tecnologia</option>
        <option value="v8">Biologia</option>
        <option value="v9">Programação</option>
        <option value="v10">Banco de dados</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se usar GET    --> $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];

Se usar POST   --> $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];

O value do option selecionado será enviado e valor do option  será armazenado na variável categoria, que poderá se transportado para inserir no banco as informações.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Escolha a categoria:</p>

    <select name="categoria">
       <option value="v1">Conhecimentos gerais</option>
       <option value="v2">Português</option>
       <option value="v3">Matemática</option>
    </select>

    <?php  
       $var = $_POST['categoria'];
       //  ou $_GET
    ?>
```

O valor do parametro **categoria** que esta vindo por **POST**, assim como mencionado pelo querido `Wellson Almeida`, será guardado na variavel **$var** e assim você pode usar essa **$var** e envia-la para seu banco.

Uma dica: Você pode filtrar esses dados do parametro através de um array, por exemplo:

em vez de usar -> **name="categoria"** use **name="categoria[]"**
isso retorna um array e apartir dai você pode percorrer esse array com um foreach por exemplo...